# filter higher order func explained

Tags: javascript

new here, Can someone help elaborate on this for me? I have been trying to understand why doesn't "new" pop up in the return or the console log.

```js
let words = ['spray', 'limit', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'elite', 'present']
const appendedWords = words.filter( (word, index , arr) => {
  arr.push('new')
  return word.length < 7
})

console.log(appendedWords)
```

Comment: You got that example from the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) docs which is _great_ that you're reading this stuff and learning. But you missed this early paragraph: _"The range of elements processed by filter() is set before the first invocation of callbackFn."_. So it means you can't modify the array like that and expect that element to appear in the result.

Comment: As mentioned by @Andy
[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#:~:text=The%20range%20of,not%20be%20visited.)

Comment: `arr` is a temporary copy of the array, and if you console.log() `arr` before and after the .push(), you'll indeed see 'new' appended multiple times to the end of `arr`. But this is only within the scope of the .filter() function. The iterator stops after 6 items. Essentially, .filter() or .map() or any other higher order function can never return more items than originally existed.

Answer (score 0):

The filter method runs all of the array elements against a function that you provide and if they meet the criteria. Then it will create a new array and store that element. `.filter()` does not modify the original array it is considered **immutable**.

You can just read the value of the original array but cannot modify it.